# How to display blanks in Crystal Reports? (when there is / are no data)

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

1. I have a date field *Table1.Dates* with the dates of the whole month of September:
2. I have a field *Table2.Sales* with sales data in **SOME** dates in September
3. I have a field *Table3.Expenses* with the expenses data in **SOME** dates in September.

Question -- :

How do I display a blank (or maybe "$0.00") **where there are no data of sales / expenses** in that day?

```
DATE ~ SALES ~ EXPENSES
-----------------------

 09/01/2014 ~ **$0.00** . . ~ $500.00

 09/02/2014 ~ $320.00  ~ **$0.00**

 09/03/2014 ~ **$0.00**  . . ~ **$0.00**

...

 09/30/2014 ~ $50.00 ~ $24.00
```

I have tried --:

Querying them to join their dates but instead of displaying a blank where there is no datum, it displays the next datum where it exists regardless of grouping them by *Table1.Dates*.

Any help regarding this?
I'll try more ways and do further Googling.

### ~ UPDATE ~ (from the first solution provided)

[image]

The picture above is the actual results of precisely following the first solution's suggestion. It is the actual fields and data of *Table1*.

Although it does show the $0.00, the dates from *Table1.Dates* need yet to be displayed regardless of what data are in Table2 & Table3.

Comment: from which table you are taking the date field field and have you used outer join?

Comment: I took the date field from Table1. Yes I have used outer join "Table1 LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Dates = Table2.Date". It shows so many duplicate of dates from Table1. 09/01/2014, 09/01/2014, 09/01/2014, 09/02/2014, 09/02,2014, 09/02/2014...

Comment: ok in such a case enable the option `Select Distinct Records` in Database menu

Comment: Can you please tell how you mean "Database menu"? Do you mean right click on Database Fields in "Field Explorer"?

Comment: not in field explorer but in Database tab which comes in the line of File, Edit

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2010. There's only: **File, Edit, View, Project, Build, Debug, Team, Data, Format, Tools Architecture, Test, Crystal Reports, Analyze, Window, Help**

Comment: Under **Crystal Reports** there is: Insert, Database, Report, Design ... Under Database there is only Database Expert, Set Database Location, Log on or off server, verify database ...

Comment: I dont know which version you are using but under database there will be select distinct records....i work on crystal as a standalone tool

Answer (score 1):

you can doe something like below:

1. First instead of `inner join` on `Table1.Dates` use `Outer Join`... since this table has all dates for the September month.
2. Group the report using `Table1.Dates`.
3. For Sales and Expences write below formula:

   ```
   if Table1.Dates=Table2.Dates //Assuming Table two also consists of Date field
   Then "$"+ToText(Sales)
   else "$"+ToText(0)
   ```

repeat same formula for Expences.

Let me know how it goes

Comment: I get an error highlight in "Table1" saying "a number, currency, amount, boolean date, time, date-time or string is expected here." I have already changed it in my MS Access design to "Short Date" format, reset my dataset, but still get the error.

Comment: can you show the formula you wrote and what is the field you are using in `Table1`

Comment: I copied your exact code. And I am positive my field name is "Dates" which is Date/Time datatype in MS Access. Also reset my dataset, rebuild solution and verify database.

Comment: I just gave an example code what is the datatype of `Table1.Dates`... please change as per your requirment

Comment: Ah okay I need curly brackets. I changed to {Table1.Dates} also the other. But after I put it, I get error highlight in (Sales) saying "Not enough arguments have been given to this function.

Comment: we are just comparing dates in the formula nothing complex there

Comment: I tried to change (Sales) to {Table1.Sales} now I get no error. I will proceed now to see.

Comment: ok now it is pointing to ToText function... have you used the same code.. cna show your code

Comment: Okay now I have only 1 line of result. 09/16/2014 ~ $5 ... I put Sales under Group Header (from tblDates.Dates) along with its Group Name. I'll try to put Sales under Details section, or also the Group Name itself.

Comment: you can put in details section... and try for result... to my assumption solution should work... :)

Comment: I will update the results from your solution. Though not all dates are showing in the report, only show dates *WHERE THERE ARE DATA*. Thanks for sharing!